# c# File.Copy from \\127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

In C# (.NET 2.0), I have the following line of code:

```
File.Copy(fileName, @"C:\Temp\someDir\SomeFile.jpg");
```

where fileName is "\\127.0.0.1\someDir\someFile.jpg".  I get an IOException that says "The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you."

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Make sure you are running in full trust mode.

Comment: \\127.0.0.1\someDir\someFile.jpg is running under a webserver or you just want to copy from local file system?

Comment: Hello,have you try to replace 127.0.0.1 by machine name?

Comment: does "net use" show an existing connection to \\127.0.0.1? this error usually means you're trying to connect to the same share with two different sets of credentials.

Comment: What operating system is this happening on?

Comment: Try mapping to that via Explorer.  I bet it asks you for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The File class accepts path that can be [UNC](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsnetworking/g/unc-name.htm) path for server or share. So in your case File.Copy is assuming that the fileName is a UNC path of a server or share hence the copy method throws exception

```
File.Copy("\\127.0.0.1\someDir\someFile.jpg", @"C:\Temp\someDir\SomeFile.jpg");
```

I would suggest you try to use [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx)